# Library not loaded error with PySide on OSX

Tags: python, macos, install-name-tool

I moved a downloaded copy of PySide out of its original install location (/Library/PySide/2.7/site-packages/PySide) to a location on the network, so a script can access it.  However, I started to get a "Library not loaded" error.  I made a copy on my desktop for testing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_pyside_imports.py", line 2, in <module>
    import PySide.QtCore
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/user/Desktop/PySide_OSX/PySide/QtCore.so, 2): Library not loaded: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySide/libpyside-python2.7.1.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/user/Desktop/PySide_OSX/PySide/QtCore.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I have run across this issue before, and I am sure that I fixed it with a bash script that just ran install_name_tool a lot:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
install_name_tool -change @rpath/libpyside-python2.7.1.2.dylib ./PySide/libpyside-python2.7.1.2.dylib ./PySide/QtCore.so
install_name_tool -change @rpath/libshiboken-python2.7.1.2.dylib ./PySide/libshiboken-python2.7.1.2.dylib ./PySide/QtCore.so
```

However, for some reason the script does not seem to resolve the issue, and QtCore.so is still looking for the library in the original location.  I checked the permissions on the files and double checked the paths in the script.  Any idea on what I am missing?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Getting closer.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
install_name_tool -change /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySide/libpyside-python2.7.1.2.dylib ./PySide/libpyside-python2.7.1.2.dylib ./PySide/QtCore.so
install_name_tool -change /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySide/libshiboken-python2.7.1.2.dylib ./PySide/libshiboken-python2.7.1.2.dylib ./PySide/QtCore.so
```

When I run the above as a bash script and then try to do an import, I get a new error:

```
D25MG1AZF8J8:PySide_OSX spearsc$ python test_pyside_imports.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_pyside_imports.py", line 2, in <module>
    import PySide.QtCore
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/spearsc/Desktop/PySide_OSX/PySide/QtCore.so, 2): Library not loaded: ./PySide/libpyside-python2.7.1.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/spearsc/Desktop/PySide_OSX/PySide/QtCore.so
  Reason: unsafe use of relative rpath ./PySide/libpyside-python2.7.1.2.dylib in /Users/spearsc/Desktop/PySide_OSX/PySide/QtCore.so with restricted binary
```

I think the issue with my first bash script is that the old path did not exist and was ignored.  Now, I need to try again but use an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

That was the trick.  I had to use absolute paths in my bash script.  All the bash script did was run 'install_name_tool' to change the old paths to the new ones.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
install_name_tool -change /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySide/libpyside-python2.7.1.2.dylib /Users/spearsc/Desktop/PySide_OSX/PySide/libpyside-python2.7.1.2.dylib /Users/spearsc/Desktop/PySide_OSX/PySide/QtCore.so
install_name_tool -change /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySide/libshiboken-python2.7.1.2.dylib /Users/spearsc/Desktop/PySide_OSX/PySide/libshiboken-python2.7.1.2.dylib /Users/spearsc/Desktop/PySide_OSX/PySide/QtCore.so
install_name_tool -change /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySide/libpyside-python2.7.1.2.dylib /Users/spearsc/Desktop/PySide_OSX/PySide/libpyside-python2.7.1.2.dylib /Users/spearsc/Desktop/PySide_OSX/PySide/libshiboken-python2.7.1.2.dylib
install_name_tool -change /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySide/libshiboken-python2.7.1.2.dylib /Users/spearsc/Desktop/PySide_OSX/PySide/libshiboken-python2.7.1.2.dylib /Users/spearsc/Desktop/PySide_OSX/PySide/libshiboken-python2.7.1.2.dylib
install_name_tool -change /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySide/libpyside-python2.7.1.2.dylib /Users/spearsc/Desktop/PySide_OSX/PySide/libpyside-python2.7.1.2.dylib /Users/spearsc/Desktop/PySide_OSX/PySide/libpyside-python2.7.1.2.dylib
install_name_tool -change /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySide/libshiboken-python2.7.1.2.dylib /Users/spearsc/Desktop/PySide_OSX/PySide/libshiboken-python2.7.1.2.dylib /Users/spearsc/Desktop/PySide_OSX/PySide/libpyside-python2.7.1.2.dylib
```

Just remember that the code snippet will just changes the paths for QtCore.so, libshiboken-python2.7.1.2.dylib, and libpyside-python2.7.1.2.dylib.  You need to run 'install_name_tool' for all of the .so files in the PySide folder as well.  In the end, my bash script was about 37-38 lines long.